# JxBrowser paragraph.findElement(By.xpath("//a")) invalid

Tags: jxbrowser

Code:

[image]

```
paragraph.findElement(By.xpath("//a")) invalid
```

Why? It's not supposed to output `123465798 66666  999999` How are they all `123465798` ?

Answer (score 0):

There are extra "//" in the `paragraph.findElement(By.xpath("a")).getInnerHTML());`